# Code interaction between classes? C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, variables

I have 2 classes, Upgrades.cs and Program.cs, In Program.cs I have a variable I want to change from Upgrades.cs the issue is, I can't set a variable in the other class or even call a method from the first class. Can someone give me an example of how to do this please? The language is C# and the program is Visual Studio 2010. This question may seem simple, but I searched everywhere and most of the help is for Unity. Since I'm using visual studio, I don't have gameObjects. Sorry.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game
{
    public partial class Upgrades : Form
    {
        public Upgrades()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static void rsc()
        {


        }
    }
}
```

I want to call a method, or change a variable from another class/script inside this one. I don't know why you asked me to add code, all I would like to do is call a completely different method, script, and class from this one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate your question to be more accurate. Why do you add C tag when there is no C? `Upgrades.cs` and `Program.cs` are files, not classes. You should not directly change member variables from other classes. To change members, use properties or functions. And until you show us your code, we can not suggest you what you can do. I would recommend you to read basic lessons for OOP and C# programming.

Comment: I know how to code C#, Not used to the lingo yet. I learned mainly through trial and error though, so that's probably why. Also updated original post.

Comment: Can you post the code of program.cs so we can see how you declared the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Upgrades
{
    public Upgrades()
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Variable = 20; //its ok.
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public int Variable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ran into some more issues,
    var program = new Program(); 
Doesn't work on VS for some reason... Instead I used
    public new Program Form1;
Which worked better, But I can't call it from a completely different script.